# how to convert a list of dataframe to json in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I want to convert below dataframes to json.

Salary :

```
         Balance before Salary   Salary
Date                                  
Jun-18                  27.20  15300.0
Jul-18                  88.20  15300.0
Aug-18                 176.48  14783.0
Sep-18                  48.48  16249.0
Oct-18                 241.48  14448.0
Nov-18                  49.48  15663.0
```

Balance :

```
             Balance
Date                                      
Jun-18  3580.661538                      
Jul-18  6817.675556                     
Aug-18  7753.483077                      
Sep-18  5413.868421                      
Oct-18  5996.120000                      
Nov-18  8276.805000                      
Dec-18  9269.000000
```

I tried:

```
dfs = [Salary, Balance]    
dfs.to_json("path/test.json")
```

but it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_json'
```

but when I tried for single dataframe, I got the following result:

```
{"Balance before Salary":{"Jun-18":27.2,"Jul-18":88.2,"Aug-18":176.48,"Sep-18":48.48,"Oct-18":241.48,"Nov-18":49.48},"Salary":{"Jun-18":15300.0,"Jul-18":15300.0,"Aug-18":14783.0,"Sep-18":16249.0,"Oct-18":14448.0,"Nov-18":15663.0}}
```

Comment: Can you tell how your expected output json will looks like

Comment: @ManojNirale: I have edited my question for easy understanding , can you please look at the question again

Answer (score 1):

You can use [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method. 
From the docs:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
...                   index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
...                   columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])

>>> df.to_json(orient='records')

'[{"col 1":"a","col 2":"b"},{"col 1":"c","col 2":"d"}]'
```

Comment: I have edited my question for easy understanding , can you please look at the question again

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for one `DataFrame` (necessary same index values in each DataFrame for alignment) and then convert to `json`:

```
dfs = [check_Salary_date, sum_Salary]    

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=np.arange(len(dfs)))
df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(b, a) for a, b in df.columns]
df.to_json("path/test.json")
```

Comment: I got an error : `ValueError: DataFrame columns must be unique for orient='columns'.`

Comment: @vrindabv - then is necessary rename columns, check edited solution